# Seeking circular novel, begins & ends with man waking from a dream

Tags: identification-request

I just heard this mentioned on a podcast, but then couldn't remember which one, and can't remember the title either! But I think it was a 3-4 word title with relatively simple, common, monosyllabic words.

It begins with a man waking up from a dream, then going to a house (possibly a party is there), and meets several people he recognizes from the dream, which he finds surprising and inexplicable. I'm not sure what else happens, but I believe it ends with his waking up from the novel's events, which *were* his dream, but which are now apparently going to be repeated in an endless cycle of dreams-within-dreams.

Comment: Finnegans Wake by James Joyce?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a lot more recent, and less complex, than Finnegan's Wake.

Comment: Finnegans Wake does not start in a dream, but it may have been the first circular novel since I can think of none before it.

Comment: Could it be Jose Luis Borges's short story (not a novel) ["The Circular Ruins"](https://www.sccs.swarthmore.edu/users/00/pwillen1/lit/cruins.htm)?